# Split in two different array of the incoming array in java

Tags: java

I have a array of values comes from the api

I want to skip the first element or nth element and process the remaining.

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your current Java code to the question.  What you asked above is not really directly answerable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ariefe gaves a wonderful answer...That is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate the array values and only skills the items needed:

```
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        
        int N = 5;

        for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
          
            if(i==0 || i == N){
                continue;
            }
            
            // now write the code to process the array value below
        }
```